# Is there a way or option to create a custom shaped button in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide, matlab-gui

How can we create a custom shaped buttons in MATLAB or is there a way to use an image and on-click do this `%calculation`?

Comment: Interesting question. I have never done that, but maybe try [this](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/45634-how-to-put-a-picture-on-a-button-in-a-gui) or [this](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/98593-how-do-i-display-an-image-on-a-gui-component-eg-pushbutton) (quick Google search)

Comment: @ Luis Mendo, Thank you!

Comment: It is possible. If you're using `figure()` then you may be able to use Java swing like [these](https://harryjoy.me/2011/08/21/different-button-shapes-in-swing/) and a good resource for using Java in matlab is [Yair's book](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/books/matlab-java). If you're using the `appdesigner` and matlab version 2019b or newer, there's a [`uihtml`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uihtml.html) component and the [options](https://travishorn.com/buttons-with-custom-shapes-cabdcde7dfd1) are endless.